# How to get iTunes-specific child nodes of RSS feeds?

Tags: php, rss, itunes

I'm trying to process [an RSS feed](http://www.npr.org/rss/podcast.php?id=510298) using PHP and there are some tags such as `'itunes:image'` which I need to process. The code I'm using is below and for some reason these elements are not returning any value. The output is length is 0.

How can I read these tags and get their attributes?

```
$f = $_REQUEST['feed'];
$feed = new DOMDocument();
$feed->load($f);
$items = $feed->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('item');

foreach($items as $key => $item) 
{
    $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    $pubDate = $item->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    $description = $item->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->textContent; // textContent

    $arrt = $item->getElementsByTagName('itunes:image');
    print_r($arrt);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByTagName` is specified by DOM, and PHP is just following that. It doesn't consider namespaces. Instead, use `getElementsByTagNameNS`, which requires the full namespace URI (not the prefix). This [appears to be](http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html#rss) `http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd`*. So:

```
    $img = $item->getElementsByTagNameNS('http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd', 'image');
    // Set preemptive fallback, then set value if check passes
    urlImage = '';
    if ($img) {
      $urlImage = $img->getAttribute('href');
    }
```

Or put the namespace in a constant.

You might be able to get away with simply removing the prefix and getting all `image` tags of any namespace with `getElementsByTagName`.

Make sure to check whether a given item has an `itunes:image` element at all (example now given); in the example podcast, some don't, and I suspect that was also giving you trouble. (If there's no `href` attribute, `getAttribute` will return either `null` or an empty string per the DOM spec without erroring out.)

<sub>**In case you're wondering, there is no actual DTD file hosted at that location, and there hasn't been for about ten years.*</sub>

Comment: This works but there is a small catch, how can I get an attribute of a element like that, the following throws me an error $item->getElementsByTagNameNS($itunes, 'image')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');

Comment: @rksh: Hmm. I'm looking into that.

Comment: @rksh: Do you have an example of the specific RSS file you're dealing with? I have one that may or may not be a good enough match.

Comment: This is my current code that's giving me trouble, I can't find an error but it gives me an error 500 page doesn't seem to load http://pastie.org/private/tjelmqlivrjhd0oin1zl3q

Comment: @rksh: OK, looks like you weren't checking for `item`s that had no `itunes:image` elements, and those were making the code choke.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$rss_feed = simplexml_load_file("url link");
if(!empty($rss_feed)) {
$i=0;
foreach ($rss_feed->channel->item as $feed_item) {    
?>
            
<?php echo $rss_feed->children('itunes', true)->image->attributes()->href;?>

<?php
}
?>
```